# Next page after Login from google account in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new in React-native , I've just confused on how can I go to next page when the Google API successfully loads to my app, most of the resources uses `React-navigation` I tried, below is my code but I think it conflicts the `react-navigation` when having a `googleSignin` how should I do it?, can anyone help me out for this.

From Login > Another link

This is what I've tried

[image]
[image]

**Login.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text } from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import {
  GoogleSignin,
  GoogleSigninButton,
  statusCodes,
} from '@react-native-community/google-signin';

GoogleSignin.configure({
  webClientId: '000000000000_test_api.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  offlineAccess: true,
});
class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      userGoogleInfo: {},
      loaded: false
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home"
          screenOptions={{
            headerShown: false
          }}>
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={LoginScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}

function LoginScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <GoogleSigninButton
        style={{ width: 222, height: 48 }}
        size={GoogleSigninButton.Size.Wide}
        color={GoogleSigninButton.Color.Dark}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}
      // onPress={this.signIn}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
async function DetailsScreen() {
  try {
    console.log("Processing");
    await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
    const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
    this.setState({
      userGoogleInfo: userInfo,
      loaded: true
    })
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.code === statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
      console.log("e 1");
    } else if (error.code === statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS) {
      console.log("e 2");
    } else if (error.code === statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
      console.log("e 3");
    } else {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  }
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Thiss is nexttt page Screen or to another jsfile</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
    padding: 15,
  },
  buttons: {
    width: 20
  }
});

export default Login;
```

**Login.js** This is the original file without implementing `react-navigation` I just want to apply next page after google account successfully login

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, ToastAndroid, Button, Text, Image } from "react-native";
import TouchID from 'react-native-touch-id';
import {
  GoogleSignin,
  GoogleSigninButton,
  statusCodes,
} from '@react-native-community/google-signin';
import { dummyData, COLORS, SIZES, FONTS, icons, images } from '../constants';
GoogleSignin.configure({
  webClientId: '12412412412000_test.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  offlineAccess: true, // if you want to access Google API on behalf 
});
class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      userGoogleInfo: {},
      loaded: false
    }
  }
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Login',
  };
  signIn = async () => {
    try {
      console.log("Processing");
      await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
      const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
      this.setState({
        userGoogleInfo: userInfo,
        loaded: true
      })
      console.log(this.state.userGoogleInfo);
      console.log(this.state.userGoogleInfo.user.name)
      console.log(this.state.userGoogleInfo.user.email)
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.code === statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
        console.log("e 1");
      } else if (error.code === statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS) {
        console.log("e 2");
      } else if (error.code === statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
        console.log("e 3");
      } else {
        console.log(error.message);
      }
    }
  };
  signOut = async () => {
    try {
      console.log("Sign out");
      await GoogleSignin.revokeAccess();
      await GoogleSignin.signOut();
      this.signIn();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  };
  biometric = async () => {
    TouchID.authenticate('Authenticate with fingerprint') // Show the Touch ID prompt
      .then(success => {
        console.log(success.message);
        console.log("success");
        // Touch ID authentication was successful!
        // Handle the successs case now
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("error");
        console.log(error.message);
        // Touch ID Authentication failed (or there was an error)!
        // Also triggered if the user cancels the Touch ID prompt
        // On iOS and some Android versions, `error.message` will tell you what went wrong
      });

  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <GoogleSigninButton
          style={{ width: 222, height: 48 }}
          size={GoogleSigninButton.Size.Wide}
          color={GoogleSigninButton.Color.Dark}
          onPress={this.signIn}
        />
        {this.state.loaded ?
          <View>
            <Text>{this.state.userGoogleInfo.user.name}</Text>
            <Text>{this.state.userGoogleInfo.user.email}</Text>
            <Image
              style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
              source={{ uri: this.state.userGoogleInfo.user.photo }}
            />
          </View>
          : <Text>Not SignedIn</Text>}
        <View style={{ width: 160, marginTop: 10 }}>
          <Button
            onPress={this.signOut}
            title="Use other account"
            color="#24A0ED"
            accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this primary" />
        </View>
        <View style={{ width: 160, marginTop: 10 }}>
          <Button
            onPress={this.biometric}
            title="Fingerprint"
            color="#24A0ED"
            accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this primary" />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
    padding: 15,
  },
  buttons: {
    width: 20
  }
});
export default Login;
```

**Apps.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Transaction, TevDetail, Login } from "./screens";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';
import Tabs from "./navigation/tabs";


const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    SplashScreen.hide()
  }, [])
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false
        }}
        initialRouteName={'Login'}
      >
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={Tabs}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="TevDetail"
          component={TevDetail}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Transaction"
          component={Transaction}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Login"
          component={Login}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Mixing navigation and screens isn't best, when you want to scale your code it will be very hard to maintain navigation and screen code in one file so i would suggest refactor it and use best of directory structure in react-native

```
.
├── src                             # Source files
│   ├── assets                      # Assets of the project (images, fonts and etc.)
│   ├── components                  # Reusable components (Like Button, InputField, LoadingIndicator, and etc.)
│   ├── pages                       # All pages folder and files
│   │    ├── login                  # e.g Login folder to contains login page related files
│   ├── navigation                  # Redux folder will contain all redux related folder and filesz
│   │    ├── AuthStack.js           # Navigation configuration related to auth stack which will be shown when user is not logged in.
│   │    ├── AppStack.js            # Navigation configuration related to app stack which will be shown when user is logged in.
│   │    ├── index.js               # Main navigation file which will render AuthStack or AppStack based user authentication status.
│   ├── utils                       # Utils folder is for utility and libraries to reuse the functions in the project
├── package.json                    # Meta data of the project
└── README.md
```

**navigation/index.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import AppStack from './AppStack';
import AuthStack from './AuthStack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

class Navigator extends Component {

    render() {
        const { isLoggedIn } = this.props;
        return (
            <Stack.Navigator>
                {
                    isLoggedIn ?
                    <Stack.Screen name="App" component={AppStack} />
                    : <Stack.Screen name="Auth" component={AuthStack} />
                }
            </Stack.Navigator>
        );
    }
}

export default Navigator;
```

I hope you know where to get isLoggedIn state/prop in the navigation index.js file

So here you can see how navigation/index.js rendering the stack based on user logged in status.
AuthStack.js you configure your pages which will be shown before user logged in and AppStack.js you configure your pages which will be shown when user is logged in.

Comment: Thanks for your response I've added my `App.js` above and my directory image, should I put `login.js` inside screens folder?

Comment: As you have screens folder which is same as pages then it's fine but as i told move your navigation related configuration in the navigation as i suggested and render the stack conditionally based on the login status so need to have home and login screen in the same navigation.

Comment: I'm sorry that I can't understand directly, should I add your code above `index.js` and paste it inside navigation? please guide me

Comment: I think you still didn't understand what i am trying to say, please go through docs once https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow and you will learn everything.